# how to fetch data from json schema? error shown-TypeError: string indices must be integers

Tags: python, json, loops, instagram-api

I have a json response from an API in this way:-

```
 {
"meta":  {
"code": 200
},
"data":  {
"username": "luxury_mpan",
"bio": "Recruitment Agents\nThe most powerful manufacturers,\nwe have the best quality.\nWechat:13255996580\nWhatsapp：+8618820784535",
"website": "",
"profile_picture": "https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-19/10895140_395629273936966_528329141_a.jpg",
"full_name": "Mpan",

 "counts":  {
   "media": 17774,
  "followed_by": 7982,
  "follows": 7264
 },

 "id": "1552277710"
 }
}
```

I want to fetch the data in "media", "followed_by" and "follows" and store it in three different lists as shown in the below code:--

```
for r in range(1,5):
    var=r,st.cell(row=r,column=3).value
    xy=var[1]
    ij=str(xy)
    myopener=Myopener()
    url=myopener.open('https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/'+ij+'/?access_token=641567093.1fb234f.a0ffbe574e844e1c818145097050cf33')
    beta=json.load(url)
    for item in beta['data']:
        list1.append(item['media'])
        list2.append(item['followed_by'])
        list3.append(item['follows'])
```

When I run it, it shows the error **TypeError: string indices must be integers**
How would my loop change in order to fetch the above mentioned values?

Also, Asking out of curiosity:- Is there any way to fetch the Watzapp no from the "BIO" key in data dictionary?

I have referred questions similar to this and still did not get my answer. Please help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`beta['data']` is a dictionary object. When you iterate over it with `for item in beta['data']`, the values taken by `item` will be the *keys* of the dictionary: `"username"`, `"bio"`, etc.

So then when you ask for, e.g., `item['media']` it's like asking for `"username"['media']`, which of course doesn't make any sense.

It isn't quite clear what it is that you want: is it just the stuff inside `counts`? If so, then instead of `for item in beta['data']:` you could just say `item = beta['data']['counts']`, and then `item['media']` etc. will be the values you want.

As to your secondary question: I suggest looking into *regular expressions*.

Comment: Thank you for your response.  I want the data inside "counts". Which means, number of "media", number of "followed-by" and number of "follows". After looking at you answer I changed my loop as: ' for item in beta['data']['counts']:  list1.append(item['media'])'  It gives the same error

Comment: For the same reason. `beta['data']['counts']` is a dictionary, and when you iterate over it with `for` you get its keys, which are just strings. The thing you want to be indexing with `'media'` etc. is `beta['data']['counts']` itself.

Comment: Is the reason why you want a loop there that you are anticipating some situation in which this JSON object has multiple things in it with keys media, followed\_by, and follows? If so, I think you need to say more about what those multiple things will be.

Comment: Well I have more than a 100  User ID's which I will be giving as an input to the API. For each API response for an ID, I get the above JSON result. So in each API call i want to get the data in "media", "follows" and "followed_by" and add it to 3 different lists (list 1, list 2 and list3). That is the reason I was putting a for loop.

Comment: But each of those is for a different JSON response, right? So the `for` loop you need will be *outside* the code you posted, not inside it. For each user ID, make the API call, parse the JSON, retrieve `beta['data']['counts']['media']` etc., and add them to your lists.

Comment: Exactly. Each of those will be for a different JSON response.  I am still not getting the output. Do you mind providing the code for the same Please?  To make it more clear my List1 should have 17774 as the value, List2 -7982 and List3- 7264 according to the JSON response I provided above. I am stil not getting my code right.

Comment: Have you tried doing what I suggested in my answer? If so, what happens when you run the code? (Your code, as shown here, doesn't initialize `list1`, `list2` and `list3`; I assume that's just because you didn't copy in the relevant initializations.)

Comment: Yes I tried Gareth! And the lists are initialized. I just didnt put up in the code above. Do I need to put the code like this:- `for item in beta['data']['counts']:` and then `list1.append(item['media'])` ?

Comment: No. I am suggesting that you *do not need a `for` loop in this part of your code*. I am suggesting that instead of `for item in beta['data']['counts']:` you just say `item = beta['data']['counts']`. There is nothing here that needs looping over.

Comment: OMG! I am so sorry I took so long to understand that! Thank you so much for being so patient Gareth. I really appreciate it!  Its just a lot of work pressure that I didnt read what you wrote in your first answer properly. I got the result. Thanks again!